# Should a class without instance variables be considered a class?

Tags: design, object-oriented, objective-c

Say you need to implement a few closely related functions that provide a piece of functionality, but there is no need to track any state between those functions, they just sometimes pass some parameters between themselves. What would be the best decision from the design standpoint? Make it a class, or just a separate source file that contains these functions?

UPD: Objective-C, no namespaces

Comment: [1986 - Brad Cox and Tom Love create Objective-C, announcing "this language has all the memory safety of C combined with all the blazing speed of Smalltalk." Modern historians suspect the two were dyslexic.](http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2009/05/brief-incomplete-and-mostly-wrong.html)

Comment: @MasonWheeler It's not without its advantages though :)

Comment: Not immediately relevant, but there is a [draft proposal](http://www.optshiftk.com/2012/04/draft-proposal-for-namespaces-in-objective-c/) to add namespaces to Objective-C.

Comment: @KeithThompson who is that guy that wrote the draft? Just a random guy or an Apple/LLVM employee?

Comment: @tux91: I don't know.

Comment: Why not ask yourself the other question, is a "class" with only state variables and no behavior really a "class"?

Comment: @tux91 he's with the Omni Group.

Comment: @CrazyEddie That's just data structure, the primary goal of classes is to abstract through providing interfaces. A class with no methods would have no interface.

Comment: @GrahamLee might not make it then, Objective-C is gonna be replaced with something else anyway, as OS X discontinues

Comment: @MasonWheeler I am agnostic about whether there really is a dog. Maybe they should have said, the blazing OO capabilities of C combined with the simplicity of SmallTalk?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're in a language that requires that all functions be part of a class (Java, C#, etc,) you don't have much of a choice but to make them part of a class.  Otherwise, just put them in their own file with its own namespace. That keeps things simpler.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I thought initially, keeps things simpler

Comment: Yeah I don't know why people are allergic to stand-alone functions.

Comment: I also find the class approach preferable in languages which don't have namespaces (like PHP <=5.2).

Comment: @tux91: so what do you think now?

Comment: Free functions are ok, at least until you have to swap the set of functions with another set. Then a class with an interface / virtual base class is better. Stateless codec are an example where this kind of 'swapping' is needed.

Answer (score 9):

You can group those functions into utility classes. [Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) in Java is a good example of this. It has no state and just lets you make static calls to do things. Putting these related methods in a class makes it clear that they are, in fact, related.

Comment: `Math` in Java is a good example of a *terrible, terrible design*. Not something I'd ever want anyone to follow.

Comment: Regardless of religious opinion about utility classes in Java; this is the idiom that is historically most correct for Java.

Comment: Java has a lot of weird things people do in order to work around the fact that everything has to be a class though.  You've shown one...another are objects with nothing but get/set pairs for every variable in the class.  That's a record, not a class!

Comment: **"things people do in order to work..."** you could stop right there @CrazyEddie - as [Stroustroup said](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup "quote source"), there are only two kinds of languages: the ones people complain about and the ones nobody uses.

Answer (score 3):

Sure!  Encapsulating data is certainly not the most important thing about OO!

```
struct thingy;

void fun(thingy & t) { t.do_stuff(); }

struct thingy {
   virtual ~thingy() {}
   virtual void do_stuff() = 0;
}

struct thingy_d1 : thingy {
  void do_stuff() { std::cout << "Doing stuff.\n"; }
};
struct thingy_d2 : thingy {
  void do_stuff() { std::cout << "Doing other stuff.\n"; }
};
```

The Command Pattern very often takes this form.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that example? At least in C++ one would use `std::function` or `boost::function` to store functions, so the advantage of what you show isn't really clear.

Comment: McConnell says that if only one object of a particular class in going to be created that it probably should even be in the app's class hierarchy, with the exception of singletons

Comment: Not that he's an absolute authority to me or anything, just saying. Something kinda seems funky to me about classes with no internal state

Comment: Your example does have state, actually; you just don't see it because the compiler generates it behind the scenes.  But in order for the virtual methods to work, there needs to be a vtable, and a vtable pointer on the `thingy`.  That's state data.

Comment: @MasonWheeler - no, that's meta-data.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's definitely a `class`, but I generally wouldn't refer to it as a 'class' in the OO sense of things as they're usually used in different ways.

For instance, in languages that lack free functions like Java, this is the workaround to provide them.

In C++ this is commonly used for function objects.

In your case it seems like a `class` provides no advantages and so you're better off having them be free functions possibly in a namespace.

Comment: That's what I thought too. Problem is, I program in objective-c, which doesn't have namespaces. Also, going with free functions they would have to be C-style functions as opposed to objective-c-style functions, which have named parameters, which I think is very convenient. On the other hand, this would entitle me to use static methods and the whole thing will just look like it's dealing with objects, which it is really not.

Comment: @tux91 Classes tend to be a poor replacement for namespaces, although I don't know enough ObjC to know what's best in your case.

Answer (score 1):

There is a major difference that seems to be forgotten about classes vs namespace.

Classes can be extended, where as namespaces can't. Even in the scenario that you describe, it is unlikely that it can be totally ruled out that in future there won't be a reason to extend your group of functions to provide a slightly altered group of functions. And in that scenario the instantiation of the class has a property, which is the type of class.

In some languages where static methods cannot be overloaded in inheriting classes, a class with only static methods could be considered as nothing more than a namespace.

Comment: This specific set of functions is for a specific task that will only be used in one place of the source code, and there's really no point of having just one subclass of a class

Comment: @tux91 do you mean in your scenario there is no point of having just one subclass of a class? if not, i disagree, unless the base class is abstract. If you are so absolutely sure that there is not any possibility of an use for subclass, then you should probably use prefixes to your functions instead!

Comment: Why would you want just one subclass of a class? Put the subclass functionality in the base class, and therefore reduce the complexity.

Comment: @tux91, because you may still need the original functionality of the base class.

Comment: The subclass never has less functionality than the base class though

Comment: @tux91 thats not quite correct. The subclass can overload some of the functionality, thus altering its behaviour, not just adding to it.

Comment: [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Subclasses must be usable through the base class interface without the need for the user to know the difference

Comment: @tux91 yup. I don't see how that is contrary to anything I have pointed out. Basically you can have different objects of the base class or subclass that other parts of program can use interchangeably without knowing their difference. When these objects are invoked, they will behave differently. So that is exactly why it does make sense to have even just one subclass of a class.

Comment: If they behave differently than they cannot be used interchangeably, this would lead to indeterministic results. You better off having a base class define a virtual method, and two subclasses to implement different behaviours then.

Comment: Your two subclasses will behave differently too to the base class then. virtual methods are only available in some OO languages like C++. In others all methods are virtual. As such the non-virtual methods are a very special thing in C++. Now to get back to the subject, in your 2 sub-classes scenario, what if you just instantiate the base class? This comes back to my point that the base class would need to be abstract. I disagree that all classes that have sub-classes should be abstract.

Comment: @tux91 Think about it, if you were right about it then most compilers/interpreters would through warnings if a non-abstract class gets extended.

Comment: I'm not talking about virtual methods in a technical sense, just methods with empty body that are meant to be overridden in subclasses. Back to the subject, subclasses should extend the base class, not override it, unless a method is virtual or is specifically meant to be overridden. Otherwise you made a mistake when implementing a function in the base class, since you assumed _this is the behaviour that all objects of class **** (and any classes derived from it) have_.  Altering the existing behaviour of an existing class, is best done with containment instead of inheritance.

Comment: **Extending** is one thing, **altering** existing behaviour is another. You break the interface by altering existing behaviours. And that's about the worst thing you can ever do in an OO design.

Comment: @tux91, again I disagree. You can alter behaviour without altering the interface. If this breaks functionality, then encapsulation wasn't observed properly. What you mean by virtual methods are abstract methods in my terminology. So we are not so much in disagreement.

Comment: What does encapsulation have to with that at all? Are you sure you are not confusing encapsulation and abstraction?

Comment: Another [wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem) describing a classical problem for you

Comment: @tux91 sorry, yes I mean abstraction (getting late here). I am aware of the circle ellipse problem and that is a very specific problem. I never said that what I've mentioned above can be applied for everything. I only said that scenarios exist that meet all of the LSP requirements. If there wouldn't be, then compilers and interpreters should not allow non-abstract classes to have sub-classes. So far I haven't seen any that do such thing.

Comment: Sure, there are such scenarios. It's just that I believe it's beneficial to stick to recommended OOP practices and have a particular thing not break rather than hope it doesn't break (even if it's unlikely).

Comment: @tux91 okay let me give you an example that is absolutely safe:

Have a base class (A) that contains a set formulas. This set of formulas  internally uses libA to do the calculation, which is readily available. But libA is computationally expensive. Here comes libB, which is only available on a few platforms, but much faster. Both libA and libB produce the same results, only using different algorithms. So you create a subclass (B) with libB that extends A. Now the rest of the program expects A and knows nothing about B, yet when gets provided with B, it can use it safely.

Comment: Why not put that code in A if it doesn't break anything and is better at the same time? That is what I think exactly started this discussion :) And I'm not saying breaking LSP **always** breaks your code, I'm saying it just might so it's a good idea to avoid it. You don't lose anything.

Comment: @tux91 because its not available on all platforms and you want it to work even without libB.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3445/discussion-between-d-inevitable-and-tux91)

Comment: @tux91 - "Why would you want just one subclass of a class? Put the subclass functionality in the base class, and therefore reduce the complexity." -- Because you might want to keep the base's clients from coupling to behavior they don't need. -- " You break the interface by altering existing behaviours." -- Not true at all.  You break an interface by violating its contract.  The whole entire purpose of polymorphism is the ability to change behaviors.  Displaying data on a printer rather than screen, for example.

Comment: @CrazyEddie 1) You're not coupling base class clients from behaviour of subclasses any more than if you coupled them with the behaviour of the base class. They should be able to use the subclass just as they use the base class. 2) Polymorphism exists not inside the inheritance tree but along the lines of derived classes. Think talk() for Dog and Cat. They derive from Animal which contains empty talk() which is meant to be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

A class defines how objects are created.  If the object does not require an internal state, the class won't have any instance variables.  There are lots of reasons why this might be useful--things like objects implementing the Strategy pattern spring to mind.

Answer (score -1):

No. That's a `namespace`. Calling it a `class` is just silly. Why would you pointlessly wrangle one feature into becoming ... a feature that the language already provides as first class?

Comment: No namespaces in objective-c, only stupid prefixes before function names, updated the question